# dependent property does not change when changed via the view setter of a listview during design time

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, properties, design-time

```
[Category("SomeCat")]
[Description("Gets or sets how items are displayed in the ShellListView control.")]
[DefaultValue(View.Details)]
new public View View
{
    get { return base.View; }
    set
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("View");

        if (value != View.LargeIcon)
        {
            //Reset these values because they can only be true if LargeIcon is set.
            ShowExtraLargeIcons = false;
        }

        base.View = value;
    }
}    

private bool m_ShowExtraLargeIcons;

[Category("Appearance")]
[DefaultValue(false)]
public bool ShowExtraLargeIcons
{
    get { return m_ShowExtraLargeIcons; }
    set
    {
        if (m_ShowExtraLargeIcons == value) 
            return;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Extra");

        m_ShowExtraLargeIcons = value;

        if (m_ShowExtraLargeIcons)
        // Always set view to LargeIcon if ShowExtraLargeIcons is enabled
            View = View.LargeIcon;
    }
}
```

My problem: If I set View to something else than LargeIcons (via the property manager of VS 2010), the ShowExtraLargeIcons-property remains True although it has been set to False.

If I set the ShowExtraLargeIcons to True, the property View is set to LargeIcons as expected.

Something that might help: The Debug-messages ("View" and "Extra") after setting ShowExtraLargeIcons are shown, after setting View they are not (both set during design time).

Comment: You make it to complicated... Maybe just View property? Why do you need that boolean thing?

Comment: Now, I implemented my own View (with a different name) that does not need this boolean any longer. thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with dependency properties, it's simply the behavior of the property browser.

When you use the new modifier on a class member, you are not creating an "override". `ListView.View` is not a virtual property. You are creating a completely new property (`MyListView.View`) which has the same signature and name.

The property browser is going to enumerate properties and use descriptors to work with them. It will see two completely different properties and either display both of them, or pick one arbitrarily.

Comment: thanks, that's it! that also explains why the Debug-Output is not displayed when changing the view property

Answer (score 0):

```
new public View
```

Looks like you are editing some parant object if trace is not shown. And that paranet object is edited without influencing m_ShowExtraLargeIcons var.